# Can't run pg_dump from cron job

Tags: linux, postgresql

Our system is on AWS. Debian EC2 instance. RDS postgres instance. 
when I log into the "admin" account pd_dump works.

```
$ whom
admin

$pd_dump 
[it works...]
```

then I `crontab -e` in order to create a test backup event.

```
*/2 * * * * /home/admin/storage/db_backup.sh
```

and indeed, it runs every 2 minutes.

in `db_backup.sh` I have:

```
pg_dump > dbbackup.txt
```

the script and the folder I am running at belong to "admin".

The dbbackup.txt is always generated with a zero size.

why is that?

Comment: Maybe pg_dump is not in the PATH ? -->> use an absolute pathname, or set the PATH inside your cron script.

Comment: And do you mean p**g**_dump or p**d**_dump? You keep using both, but postgres's command is **pg_dump**.

Comment: I am running absolute path. pg_dump runs. it just craps out on errors which make the output 0.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of your script? What arguments are you sending to pg_dump? Is your script when run by cron not generating any output on stderr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can only guess here, but I have a suggestion. Try redirecting ALL output (including stderr) to the file to see if it gives you some information.

in your `/home/admin/storage/db_backup.sh` add `2>&1`:

```
pg_dump > dbbackup.txt 2>&1
```

you may also use this and redirect your cron line in case your `.sh` file has some problems:

```
*/2 * * * * /home/admin/storage/db_backup.sh >> /home/admin/cron_log.txt 2>&1
```

EDIT: just noticed you post an answer already. Buy if you'll have time, try removing exports and see if you can get some errors in logs that may help.

Comment: @RM1970 Could you, please, comment if this really could help solve your issue?

Answer (score 5):

I found out what the culprit was. Since I'm ran in the context of admin but in cron, my environment strings were not set.

setting this at the head of my `db_backup.sh` resolved this:

```
export PGPASSWORD=<value>
export PGHOST=<value>
export PGDATABASE=<value>
export PGUSER=<value>
```

Comment: Finally, after one week

Comment: For security reasons, it's better to use a .pgpass file instead. So I suggest replacing `export PGPASSWORD=<value>` with `export PGPASSFILE=<path to .pgpass file>`. See the documentation for more: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-envars.html

Answer (score 0):

According to my mac, the zero dump files were caused because `crontab` couldn't understand `pg_dump`.

Instead, I did the following. FYI I use connection string URI.

But what's important is the full path I set to the pg_dump

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://admin:D%40t%40sc13nc3@localhost:5432/digitaldairy | gzip > test1232323.gz
```